# Xcache var_size error

Tags: php, zend-framework, xcache

I am trying to use xcache with zend framework to cache the metadata from Zend_Db_Table_Abstract so that describe queries are only called once per table.  When implementing xcache into my bootstrap and running the application, I am being presented with the following error:

```
Warning: xcache_get() [function.xcache-get]: xcache.var_size is either 0 or too small to enable var data caching in /home/randall/htdocs/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/Xcache.php on line 95.
```

I have adjusted the settings in my php.ini:

```
; XCACHE
 626 [xcache-common]
 627 zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20060613/xcache.so
 628 
 629 [xcache-admin]
 630 xcache.admin.enable_auth = On
 631 xcache.admin.user = "user"
 632 xcache.admin.password = "********"
 633 
 634 [xcache]
 635 xcache.shm.scheme = "mmap"
 636 xcache.size = 128M
 637 xcache.count = 4
 638 xcache.slots = 8K
 639 xcache.ttl = 0
 640 xcache.gc_interval = 0
 641 
 642 xcache.var_size = 64M
 643 xcache.var_count = 1
 644 xcache.var_slots = 8K
 645 xcache.var_ttl = 0
 646 xcache.var_maxttl = 0
 647 xcache.var_gc_interval = 300
 648 xcache.test = Off
 649 
 650 xcache.readonly_protection = Off
 651 xcache.mmap_path = "/tmp/xcache"
 652 xcache.coredump_directory = ""
 653 
 654 xcache.cacher = On
 655 xcache.stat = On
 656 xcache.optimizer = Off
 657 
 658 [xcache-coverager]
 659 xcache.coverager = On
 660 xcache.coveragedump_directory = ""
```

but i still continue to get the error no matter what I set the xcache.var_size parameter to.  This occurs on xcache 1.2.2 and 1.3.0.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See as well: http://drupal.org/node/570264

Comment: XCache Bug: http://xcache.lighttpd.net/ticket/228

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run a `phpinfo()`, and see if those settings are accurate/to make sure the correct php.ini is loaded.  Also, try setting the mmap_path to "/dev/zero" (All it does is disable readonly_protection, which you don't have enabled anyway)...

Comment: Thanks for the help. Running the php info showed that xcache was being loaded twice. Once from the php.ini and then an xcache.ini. I removed the xcache.ini (copied it to .old) and restarted apache and error went away.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Doctrine CLI commands. Changing the var_size or the mmap_path had no effect. To get the errors to go away, I removed/commented out all references to Xcache from php.ini. The commands and my web application still worked afterwards but the errors were gone.