# can't find xcache.var_size in php.ini

Tags: php, xcache

I need to change the xcache.var_size in the php.ini file.
The problem that I can't seem to find it there. I have varified that this is the right on eby using phpinfo();

Comment: You could always just add it.

Comment: how is it supposed to look? like this [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976829/xcache-var-size-error or just Xcache var_size =16M;

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the value is not being loaded from another ini file. PHP could load multiple ini files. If it is not present in any of the ini files, then you might be seeing the default value. In which case, you can overwrite it by adding it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

check /etc/php5/mods-available/xcache.ini